# JQuery mobile 100% height page, which equals visible area

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a problem dealing with the website height on an iphone. The following set up works pretty well on all other devices (ipad,android phones), but on an iphone device the site height won't get updated after the url bar disappears and a blank area is visible at the bottom of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>temp</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-page{
                min-height: 100% !important;
            }
        </style>    
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <div data-role="page" id="loadscreen" data-theme='c'>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" onClick="window.scrollTo(0, 1)">Scroll Up</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Site: http://jsfiddle.net/hb8NH/2/

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
.ui-page{
    min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

JQueryMobile calculates the necessary height and sets the Min-Height style to the Page to make sure it fills the entire page.

You'll notice that on an iPhone in Safari (after removing the min-height) that you get a slight over scroll available that will hide your "Scroll Up" text. JQueryMobile is calculating the min height based on screen size i believe. That way if saved to the home screen of the iphone (where there are no safari toolbars, header or footer) your page will still fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

To

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

It shure does the trick for me.

Comment: Sorry, didn't worked for me. Still the same problem on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set webView native property :

```
    // fix orientation issue
 [webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
```

**That work for me.**

Comment: Well, that is the wrong language you are talking about ;)